# Shared Elements Transition from Gridview not launching from right location

Tags: android, gridview

I have a gridview with cardviews displaying an ImageView on the main activity. I'm trying to have a shared element transition from the image to the details activity.

Here is the relevant section from MainActivity

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/showGrid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="16dp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The xml for the item

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/showCard"
android:layout_width="180dp"
android:layout_height="180dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:elevation="8dp"
android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/showLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/rth"
    android:transitionName="logoImage" />
```

And the xml for the DetailsActivity

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/rth"
                android:transitionName="logoImage"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Here's the java from MainActivity

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FeedActivity.class);

            Show show = (Show) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            intent.putExtra("selectedShow", show);

            ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this, (View)findViewById(R.id.showLogo), "logoImage");
            startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());

        }
    }
```

The transition effect happens and the correct image is shown. However, the transition always starts from the first item in the gridview. The exit transition shows the image from the detailsActivity going back to the first item in the gridview even if it's from another position.

How do I get the transition to start and exit from the item that the user selected? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `transitionName` different for each of the children of `GridView`. Then you need to figure out a way set the same `transitionName` for the corresponding detail in the `DetailsActivity`.

[Great implementation on GitHub](https://github.com/alexjlockwood/activity-transitions)

Answer (score 0):

I understand this question is old, but for anyone who needs it...

On the line

```
ActivityOptionsCompat options = 
ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(MainActivity.this, 
(View)findViewById(R.id.showLogo), "logoImage");
```

Don't use `(View)`, put `view.`

So instead of

```
(MainActivity.this, (View)findViewById(R.id.showLogo), "logoImage");
```

Use

```
(MainActivity.this, view.findViewById(R.id.showLogo), "logoImage");
```

This is because you need to reference the view that is used as the child in GridView